# Nodejs express req identificar los parámetros enviados en body del tipo form-data

Tags: nodejs, body

Quiero enviar una imagen desde mi frontend a mi backend en nodejs express y en mi ruta tengo

```js
router.post('/dato',(req, res, next)=>{
    print('req.params',req.params);
    print('req.body',req.body);
    print('req.query',req.query);
    print('req.file',req.file);
    print('req.files',req.files);
    print('req.headers',req.headers);
    // print('',);
    // print('',);
    // print('',);
    // print('',);
    // print('',);
    // print('',);
    res.send(pjson(req));

});

function pjson(valor){
    return util.inspect(valor, {showHidden: true, depth: null});
}
function print(nombre, valor){
    console.log(nombre + ": " + util.inspect(valor, {showHidden: true, depth: null}))
}
```

El problema es que no consigo identificar en donde puedo ver los datos enviados a través de postman bajo la siguiente configuración
url: localhost/dato
body->form-data->("millave","mivalor")
el caso es que en req si envio en
body->x-www-form-urlencoded->("millave","mivalor")
si obtengo en body esos parámetros pero con form-data no se donde llegan
y como quiero pasar una imagen sin usar multer Asumo que encontrando como ver lo enviado a través de body->form-data podre extraer la imagen.
Agradecería por alguien que me ayude a esclarecer eso